# Laravel Display sub categories

Tags: php, html, laravel

So i got a problem where i set up everything and tested the relationships but can't really wrap my head around how would i output the navigation correctly with nested categories this is my category model

```
public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}


public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

which works, i tested with tinker and it gets children and parents correctly
so how would one go about displaying it, this is the partial which i'm using for displaying categories and then i tried to call itself within the view, sort of like recursion, with now children, but it gets stuck on request and page won't load so i'm assuming it doesn't work like this

```
@if(count($categories))
<ul class="list-group">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/{{ $category->slug }}">{{ $category->name }}</a></li>
        @include('layouts.categories', ['categories' => $category->children])
    @endforeach
</ul>@endif
```

and this is method where i'm fetching categories, i did it this way so it can be avialable to all views, but i'm assuming this query is one that can be moddified

```
   View::composer('*', function ($view) {
        $view->with('categories', Category::all());
    });
```

my desired result is this

```
Men
 -Men's Shoes
Women
 -Women's Shoes
```

Comment: How many categories, including children, you have right now?

Answer (score 1):

If you have too many categories you'll end up with a N+1 issue.

Add this to your model:

```
public function allChildren()
{
    return $this->children()->with('allChildren');
}
```

And then your composer should be:

```
   View::composer('*', function ($view) {
        $view->with('categories', Category::with('allChildren')->all());
    });
```

If you are crashing due to multiple queries, this may solve the issue for you.

Comment: sorry for late response, i tried it but still same result